# Chrome and Firefox 70.0.1 freeze display every 5 seconds

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, display, freeze

I'm not used to post on stackoverflow but this problem is driving me crazy and no post did help me.

Every 5-10 seconds my browser (Firefox) is freezing for about 1-2 seconds. I'm on the last version of Firefox (70.0.1) on Archlinux. My pc is a HP Elitebook G3.
During the freeze I can listen to sound and input are continuing (if I click a button during the freeze, after the freeze the action would be done).

The problem is occuring since 3-4 month

When I restart my computer the problem disapear, but it comes back 10-15minuts after startup.

That's what i've tried for the moment :

- Launch Firefox without addons, without plugins
- Turn off hardware acceleration
- Refresh Firefox
- Uninstall / Reinstall Firefox
- Delete current profile
- Remove the option to save current workspace

This problem occurs on chrome too.
I'm using i3 as display manager (X) I think it's not related to this because others application do not freeze like that.

EDIT : I tried htop to see if Firefox was using too much memory, When the freeze do not occur it's between 0 and 3 % cpu usage. When the freeze occurs it bump to 20% on each core then go back to normal usage
My Mem is 1.3G/7.6G and Swap is not used (1.5M/16.5G)

EDIT2 : The bug can occur just when scrolling on a page or when charging a link. Mouse and sound are not affected

Thank you for your help

Comment: We have the same kind of Issues on the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ Operating System. As far as we understand, you are watching some kind of Internet Protocol Television Channels or Audio-Video Streaming Services. No amount of Software ReInstallation Procedures and no amount of Tested Web-Browsers have succeeded in fixing these Issues. We guess that the Audio-Video Streaming Technology is still in its infancy and that it has yet to be improved.

Comment: Are you running out of RAM and is your Firefox browser running on swap? Check with a system monitor or `free -h` or `cat /proc/swaps`. If you are not running on swap, and try garbage collection to see if that fixes the issue? To start GC, go to about:memory, and click on GC (don't save any logs, GC will generate multiple files with hundreds of megabytes in size to your /tmp/ directory). Also try clean the browser cache (from settings), try disabling cache to disk (about:config -> browser.cache.disk.enable). If they don't fix the issue, please comment with the OS you are using...

Comment: As you said, it's not running on swap, can you confirm which process of Firefox is using that much CPU? For example, on Firefox nightly, I faced a situation like this, and the gpu-process was using 100% CPU when you just move your mouse on the browser! In such case I was unable to watch youtube videos or browse normally. That bug was in Firefox nightly, the 70 - 71 beta and developer-edition versions should work fine.

Comment: @SouravGoswami I tried deactivating cache to disk but without success the problem is still there, I'm using Archlinux
My swap is not used
I'm not sure how to check which process is using the cpu but during the "lag" it's not using more than 20% on each core (tried using `htop`
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was apparently not only on Firefox and Chrome but on others applications like Aseprite for example.

I kinda solved the problem by uninstalling `xf86-video-intel`

Since that, the problem no longer occurs !

This topic helped me : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1869571

Thanks for the help